# Odd Pair of XOR in a large input Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation, xor

> You are given an array A1,A2...AN. You have to tell how many pairs (i,
>   j) exist such that 1 ≤ i < j ≤ N and Ai XOR Aj is odd.
>
> `Input and Output`  First line T, the number of testcases. Each
>   testcase: first line N, followed by N integers in next line. For each
>   testcase, print the required answer in one line.
>
> Constraints  `1 ≤ T ≤ 10  1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5  0 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^9`.

My code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int totalTestCaseT = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        StringBuilder outputOddCount = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalTestCaseT; i++) {
            int lengthOinputT = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            String input = reader.readLine().trim();
            long oddXorCount = getOddXorCount(input, lengthOinputT);
            outputOddCount.append(oddXorCount);
            outputOddCount.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println(outputOddCount);
    }

    private static long getOddXorCount(String input, int lengthOinputT) {

        String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
        int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOinputT; i++) {
        String lastDigit = String.valueOf((inputArray[i]
                    .charAt(inputArray[i].length() - 1)));
            int unitDigit = Integer.parseInt(lastDigit);
            if ((unitDigit & 1) == 1) {
                oddCount++;
            } else
                evenCount++;
        }
        return oddCount * evenCount;
    }
```

It's working for some value of N but not for large N ~100000.

Sample input: [Input 1](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/july-easy-challenge/problems/sherlock-and-xor/input-9cfd312.txt) [Input 2](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/july-easy-challenge/problems/sherlock-and-xor/input-9d92ec7.txt).

Initially I wrote it without any function with everything in the main class like this, and it passed all tests

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = br.readLine();
    int tCases = Integer.parseInt(line);

    for (int i = 0; i < tCases; i++) {
        long oCount = 0, eCount = 0;
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] A = br.readLine().toString().split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int unitDigit = Integer
                    .parseInt((A[j].charAt(A[j].length() - 1)) + "");
            if (unitDigit % 2 == 0)
                eCount++;
            else
                oCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(eCount * oCount);
    }
```

Here is both the submission of mine 
1. [Submission of code 1](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/1906611/)
2. [Submission of code 2](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/1906668/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version that works for all inputs you are using `long`s to hold the counters :

```
long oCount = 0, eCount = 0;
```

In the version that doesn't work for some inputs, you are using `int`s to hold the counters :

```
int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0;
```

Perhaps you are getting `int` overflow.

For example, if the number of even numbers is half of all the numbers, both oddCount and evenCount will be 50,000. 50,000*50,000 is 2,500,000,000 which is larger than the max value of int. Therefore `oddCount * evenCount` will overflow.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing one of my almost overlooked misconception of the return type .. i was under impression that since i'm returning `long` the two value holding the `int` value when multiplied will return the actual answer !

Comment: @AnkurAnand You're welcome. This isn't about the return type. When you are performing a numeric operation on two ints, the result is also int, even if you assign it to a variable of a different type. Just like `long l = 50000 * 50000;` will overflow, `double d = 2 / 5` will return `0.0` (instead of `0.4` that some people expect). BTW, you can still keep the counters `int` if you change the return statement to  `return (long)oddCount * evenCount;`. This will force multiplication of longs, which won't overflow.

Comment: Instead of two counters even/odd count, you can use array count[2], and accumulate values by count[unitDigit & 1]++; without any if().

Answer (score 0):

XOR of even and odd number is odd.

Hence in a given array [A1,A2...AN], find total number of even elements and total number of odd elements.

As we've to find number of all pairs having odd XOR, then answer is multiplication of total odd elements and total even elements.

Below is my solution in PHP.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: abhijeet
 * Date: 14/05/16
 * Time: 3:51 PM
 * https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/sherlock-and-xor/description/
Input and Output
First line T, the number of test cases. Each test case: first line N, followed by N integers in next line. For each testcase, print the required answer in one line.
2
3
1 2 3
4
1 2 3 4
 */
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $n);
while($n--) {
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $len);
    $a_temp = rtrim(fgets(STDIN), "\n\r");
    $a = explode(" ", $a_temp);
    array_walk($a, 'intval');
    $odd = 0;
    $even = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        if($a[$i]%2) {
            $odd++;
        } else{
            $even++;
        }
    }
    echo ($odd * $even) . "\n";
}
?>
```